# Change jtable (jquery) actions options RUNTIME

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jtable

I need to change actions options of jtable AFTER initialization:

```
$('#tab-3').jtable({
            title: 'Documenti Allegati',
            paging: true, 
            pageSize: 10, 
            sorting: true, 
            defaultSorting: 'nomefile ASC', 
            actions: {
                listAction: 'action.php?action=getAllegatiByID&id='+id,
                deleteAction: 'action.php?action=delAllegatoByID&id='+id,
                updateAction: 'action.php?action=updateAllegatiById&id='+id,
                createAction:'temp'
                    },
            fields:{
                    ...
                    }
                   ...
```

I need to edit createAction url.
i tried to search  in  $.hik.jtable.prototype.options but i didn't find it.

Can Anyone help me?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

jtable actions take either a url or a function, i.e. from http://jtable.org/Demo/FunctionsAsActions.

```
           createAction: function (postData) {
                console.log("creating from custom function...");
                return $.Deferred(function ($dfd) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Demo/CreateStudent',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: postData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $dfd.resolve(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            $dfd.reject();
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
```

You can write your own function to return:

```
function myFunc(dfd){
    return $.ajax({
                        url: myCustomUrlThatIwantToChangeDynamically,
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: postData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $dfd.resolve(data);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            $dfd.reject();
                        }
                    });
}
```

so the action can become:

```
createAction: function (postData) {
            console.log("creating from custom function...");
            return $.Deferred(myfunc($dfd););
        },
```

and then you can change your url when you need to and the createAction will use the updated URL.

Just a suggestion.